# Empty etc/default/jenkins file. How to change Jenkins port?

Tags: jenkins, port, ubuntu-18.04

I wanted to change the default Jenkins port, so obviously, I googled. I reached to the point that I have to change the port number in `/etc/default/jenkins` and then restart Jenkins with `sudo service jenkins restart`. 
Seemed pretty easy, but after executing: `"sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins/"` it appeared that my file is empty.

https://ibb.co/09yVLyP

I figured, that I will input and save the code either way:

```
"HTTP_PORT=8010
JENKINS_ARGS="--httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"
```

So after that I executed:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

but I got an error:

```
Failed to restart jenkins.service: Unit jenkins.service not found.
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Hi..WC to SO! Please go through the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking question. Also how have you installed jenkins, what is the version and what is the operating system ?

Comment: Have you checked if you have installed jenkins properly, also what happens if you run jenkins with default ports ?

Comment: I figured out what was happening. The solution was to change the port directly in docker-compose file and map it to 9090, so in general I have something that looks like: `ports: 9090:8080`